# getRelatedListRecords where clause does not accept dynamic parameters

Tags: lightning-web-components

If I hardcode the where clause with the original value (***where: '{ RecordTypeId: { eq: "0123***********AA2"} }')*** below code returns the related records but I need to get the recordtypeId before I can pass it to getRelatedListRecords wire adapter and this doesn't return the related child records. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class TransferChildBillingAccounts extends LightningElement {

@track swAccountRecTypeId; 

 @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo({error, data}) {
        if(data) {
            const recordTypes = data.recordTypeInfos;           
            this.swAccountRecTypeId = Object.keys(recordTypes).find((recordType) => recordTypes[recordType].name === 'SW Account')
        }
    }

@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListId: 'ChildAccounts',
        fields: ['Account.Name','Account.Id'],
        sortBy: ['Account.Name'],
        where: '{ RecordTypeId: { eq: $swAccountRecTypeId } }'
      })
      listInfo({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.records = data.records.map((key) => ({
                label: key.fields.Name.value,
                value: key.fields.Id.value
            }));
            console.log('result -->' + JSON.stringify(this.records));
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
          this.error = error;
          this.records = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reactivity is limited to a string that starts with $. That means your condition needs to look like:

```
where: '$whereCondition'
```

Which you'd specify in the other handler:

```
const swAccountRecTypeId = Object.keys(recordTypes).find((recordType) => recordTypes[recordType].name === 'SW Account');
this.whereCondition = `{ RecordTypeId: { eq: ${swAccountRecTypeId} } }`;
```